# Why is Eclipse platform dependent?

Tags: java, cross-platform, eclipse

When Eclipse is written in Java and Java is platform independent, why does Eclipse offer different versions according to platforms?

I assume it should be write once, use anywhere code.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps because file systems and file hierarchy are OS specific? And because Eclipse is starting OS specific programs

Comment: That's easy: Eclipse isn't written in Java. In fact, since it **contains** at least two different bundled java compiler implementations, it would be more accurate to say that (some versions of) Java are written in Eclipse!

Comment: @KillanFoth: your answer won't fit if the bundled compilers are distributed in JVM bytecode as `.jar` or `.class` files.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch do you mean the io or nio package in java is platform dependent?
I guess no. If eclipse is written in Java, It can easily utilize those classes to make the code platform independent.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OS specific programs, like .. ? I don't know about it.

Comment: I almost never used Eclipse, but some installations of it are starting external tools like some C compiler (`gcc`), some builder like `make` (or `ant`), etc.

Comment: SWT is probably one of the reasons, if not the main one.

Comment: This question already has an [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069523/is-eclipse-platform-independent).

Comment: @Caleb here it's even simpler than that. If OP would put a little bit effort to check what URLs these links refer to, they would find that these are **installers**, not Eclipse itself. eclipse-inst-mac64.tar.gz, eclipse-inst-win64.exe, eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz

Comment: @Caleb Missed that. Sorry. I thought that it is a conceptual question and hence would be closed on SO. hence searched and posted here.

Comment: @gnat Sorry, the advertisement in previous image was taking all the focus. updated that.  Please check the dropdown and links below that advertisement. They refer to files like eclipse-jee-mars-1-linux-gtk.tar.gz which I guess is the eclipse itself.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069523/is-eclipse-platform-independent. Answers given here would not differ from the answers there.

Comment: why the defaced image?

Comment: That ad was taking all the focus. Thats why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although Eclipse IDE is written in Java, the graphical control elements use [Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit), whereas most Java applications use the Java standard Abstract Window Toolkit (AWT) or Swing.

> To display GUI elements, the SWT implementation accesses the native GUI libraries of the operating system using JNI (Java Native Interface) in a manner that is similar to those programs written using operating system-specific APIs. Programs that call SWT are portable, but the implementation of the toolkit, despite part of it being written in Java, is unique for each platform.
>
> SWT must be ported to every new GUI library that needs supporting. Unlike Swing and AWT, SWT is not available on every Java-supported platform since SWT is not part of the Java release.

Therefore the Eclipse distribution must include different SWT implementation for each supported platform.